# $cacheFactory $resource page state AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I preserve page state when toggling between views as well as caching requests on a service shared between controllers?

**I have two views:**

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'views/art.html'});
$routeProvider.when('/bio', {templateUrl: 'views/bio.html'});
```

`art.html` **has a controller** `Filters`

```
.controller('Filters', ['$scope','Imgur', function($scope, Imgur) {
  $scope.$on('updateAlbumsList', function(e) {
      $scope.albumsList = Imgur.returnAlbumsList();
  });
  $scope.filterAlbum = function(id) {
    Imgur.filterAlbum(id);
  };
  $scope.init = function() {   
    Imgur.getAlbumsList(function(){
      //A hack to preserve page state
      Imgur.loadFilters();
    });
  };
  $scope.init();
}])
```

**[Here is a plunker with full source.](http://plnkr.co/akHTslTdRMvfe3KrnPeO)**

Now obviously I can do things to the service object like apply filters which can change exhisting properties, add new ones, and even add new objects per request.

But what happens when I toggle to `bio.html` and back to `art.html`? The requests get sent out again and re-renders the entire page! I understand it's because the object is being reinstantiated by `init()`.

- How do I preserve the state of the page when toggling between views?
- How do I use cached requests for identical service calls shared by other controllers?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it (I only started working with Angular about a week ago), the `Imgur` service would generally be considered to be a good place to store state in.

In my case, I have a similar situation in that I have a search directive that's used in multiple views, but whose state I want to keep between view changes. So the directive uses a service which keeps its own state: last query performed, last list of results returned by the server, etc. When the directive's `link` function is called, it initializes the scope with those values.

Which looks something like this:

```
// service
myApp.service('SearchService', function(...) {
  var previousQuery   = null;
  var previousResults = [];

  this.getPreviousQuery   = function() { return previousQuery; };
  this.getPreviousResults = function() { return previousResults; };

  this.performSearch = function(query) {
    previousQuery = query;
    ...
  };
});

// directive (but could just as well have been a controller)
myApp.directive('mySearchForm', function(..., SearchService) {
  return {
    ...
    link : function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $scope.query         = SearchService.getPreviousQuery();
      $scope.searchResults = SearchService.getPreviousResults();
      ...
    }
  };
});
```

But like I said, I'm an Angular beginner so don't know if this is a Best Practice. Also, there's other pieces of 'state' that are harder to store-and-retrieve (like scroll position into a search results list, in my case) and which I haven't been able to satisfactorily solve (only through some hackery).

Since I think services are singleton classes, and therefore instantiated once, they seem to be a good place to store state in. If you don't have a service to store state in (or it feels weird doing so), `$cacheFactory` (like you mention) is an option too. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moderndegree/yYEXN/) that helped me understand how to store and retrieve from it.